# Bash descending filename sorting

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, awk, sed

I've been trying to sort my filenames with commands similar to `ls -1 | sort -n -t "_" -k1` but just can't get it to work. Please help.

I have:

```
10_filename
11_filename
12_filename
1_filename
2_filename
```

I want to get:

```
1_filename
2_filename
... 
10_filename
11_filename
```

Comment: " just can't get it to work." What is it doing instead of working?

Comment: `sort -n -t_ -k1` works just fine for me, but just `sort -n` should work as well in this very case.

Answer (score 2):

Please try following this will solve the issue

```
ls -1v
```

-v It sorts on basis of file version versions

Comment: on linux but lot of other shell/OS does not accept the v

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**ls -1 *\_filename | sort -n**

or

ls -1 | sort -n

Answer (score -1):

```
ls -1 | sort -t '_' +1 +0n
```

below, a bit heavy but working if sort does not accept field order and using simple string sort.

```
ls -1 | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)_\(.*\)/000\1_\1_\2/;s/^0*\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1/;s/\([0-9]\{1,\}_[0-9]\{1,\}_\)\(.*\)/\2_\1/' | sort -n | sed 's/\(.*\)_[0-9]\{1,\}_\([0-9]\{1,\}\)_$/\2_\1/'
```